# want to create a protected route using useRoutes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created that app where I defined all the routes paths inside useroutes and signIn, and the login page is there. Based on login, we are giving permission to move on to the about section, so here I have created an about page as well. On the demo page, all the navigation tabs are present. So can you please correct that programmeme using useRoutes? I want to define the routes, and based on login, navigate to the about page, which is protected, and else on the home page, the programmeme is there below.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Demo from "./Demo";

function Home() {
  return <div>Home component</div>;
}

function NotFound() {
  return <div>404 Not Found Page</div>;
}

function About() {
  return <div>About Page</div>;
}
function SignIn() {
  return <div>SignIn Page</div>;
}
function LogIn() {
  return <div>LogIn Page</div>;
}
const Routes = () => {
  let routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Home />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "signin",
          element: <SignIn />,
        },
        {
          path: "login",
          element: <LogIn />,
        },
      ],
    },
    { path: "about/:id", element: <About /> },
    { path: "*", element: <NotFound /> },
  ]);
  return routes;
};
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();
  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};
export default function App() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Demo />
      <button onClick={() => setLogin(!login)}>
        {login ? "LogOut" : "LogIn"}
      </button>
      <Router>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and about page

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
export default function About({ login }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!login) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [login, navigate]);
  return <div>About component</div>;
}
```

and demo page

```
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Demo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onClick = (path) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    navigate(path);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ul
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          listStyle: "none",
        }}
      >
        <li>
          <Link to="/" onClick={onClick("/")}>
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about" onClick={onClick("/about")}>
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

here link is
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dreamy-wind-wsdhws?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A47%2C4

Comment: What exactly is the specific issue or problem you need to have addressed? Please [edit] to clarify what you need help with.

Comment: I want to implement the protected route concept in my programme using useRoutes, so if anyone wants to correct the code and make that structure

Comment: You have all the code, it seems, but you are not using the `ProtectedRoute` component. Is *this* just the part you need help with? I see in your sandbox you have an error trying to use the `useNavigate` hook outside a router.

Comment: yes not able to understand what to do next or is there any separate way to do that navigation using useRoutes

Comment: I'll suggest a duplicate target for the question of implementing and using route protection. You'll need to address the other React issues separately. The `Demo` component needs to be rendered within the `Router`, and the `useAuth` hook needs to be declared/implemented so there is a `token` value for `ProtectedRoute` to use. I didn't dig any deeper than this so there's no guarantee these are the only two additional issues.